# Which spells do Wizards get at lower levels than Sorcerers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wizard, sorcerer

For my first D&D character I chose to be a wizard because I love wizards and spellcasters in general, and I heard that wizards can learn certain spells before sorcerors can. Is this true? If so and the list isn't huge, which spells do wizards get first?

Comment: While the answers cover it nicely, there are a few class-exclusive spells to both - Sorcerer gets more of those than Wizard does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Wizards get *every* spell a level sooner, except for level 0 and level 1 spells.

See the spells per day tables on the [Sorcerers & Wizards page](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm). Wizards and sorcerers learn from the same spell list, but wizards learn each new spell level 1 class level earlier. So except for first level spells (which both classes gain at level 1), a wizard gains access to a spell level when their class level = (2 × that spell level) − 1, whereas a sorcerer gains access to a spell level when their class level =  2 × that spell level.

For example, a wizard gains access to 3rd level spells when their wizard level is 5, while a sorcerer learns 3rd level spells when their sorcerer level is 6.

Comment: oh that's how it's done I was wondering just like wtf and have been scratching my head over it for a few days now

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks, I guess I shouldn't try to answer questions on a Saturday morning....

Comment: No problem! Mixed math and English is hard to get right; I had to check my fix several times to make sure it was right. Besides, it gave me the excuse to use proper multiplication and minus signs instead of x and hyphen. :)